# "no current thread" bug when opening a file with gdal ogr (no multi threading)

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

This is a bug I cannot reproduce with simple code. I'm working with ubuntu 16.04 and gdal 2.2.3, in python3.

When I try to open a geojson with ogr in my programm:

```
src_ds = ogr.Open('/data/train/AOI_2_Vegas_Train/geojson/line/line_AOI_2_Vegas_img2389.geojson')
```

I get an error which is a segfault I guess:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

Current thread 0x00007f2bb0fcd700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/myhome/project/env/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 7923 in Open
```

but when I try it in the python console, or in a small script, it works. I extracted the part of my code leading to this bug, but when I execute it separately from the rest of my code it works:

```
import gdal
import ogr

rgb_fn = '/data/train/AOI_2_Vegas_Train/RGB-PanSharpen/RGB-PanSharpen_AOI_2_Vegas_img2389.tif'
rgb_ds = gdal.Open(rgb_fn, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

def _get_raster_properties(raster_ds):
     # get reference properties
     x_size = raster_ds.RasterXSize
     y_size = raster_ds.RasterYSize
     geotransform = raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()
     projection = raster_ds.GetProjection()
     return x_size, y_size, geotransform, projection


x_size, y_size, geotransform, projection = _get_raster_properties(rgb_ds)

line_ds = driver.Create('/tmp/line_ds.tif', x_size, y_size, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
line_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
line_ds.SetProjection(projection)

line_fn = '/data/train/AOI_2_Vegas_Train/geojson/line/line_AOI_2_Vegas_img2389.geojson'
src_ds = ogr.Open(line_fn)  # this is failing in my code, but not here

gdal.RasterizeLayer(line_ds, [1], src_ds.GetLayer(), burn_values=[1])
```

this script is the equivalent of the code I am runnig in my program, with the same file treated.

Is this a gdal bug?

Comment: in the first case you use a relative path whereas in the second case you use an absolute path. However it seems that you use different python versions in your command line than in your python script. I would recommend to use a conda environment or at least a virtual environment.

Comment: I use the same file with the same path everywhere. the 'my_path' bit was just to give an example of the command used.

Comment: gdal is only installed in this environment, which I use for both the python command and the script.

Answer (score 3):

This error has been raised for me when using `gdal.Open()` on an invalid file path. I recommend explicitly verifying all of your paths exist before handing them to gdal to make these errors a bit easier to recognize.

```
from pathlib import Path 
path = Path("my/image/path.tif")
if not path.exists():
    raise FileNotFoundError
```

or using the os module

```
import os
path = "my/image/path.tif"
if not os.path.exists(path):
    raise FileNotFoundError
```